# C language pointer

Tags: c

Write a program that uses two pointer variables to read two double numbers and display the absolute value of their sum?

this is my code and I don not know where it gets wrong:

```
int main(void)
{
    double *p1,*p2, val1,val2;
    p1 = &val1;
    p2 = &val2,
    printf("Enter  two number: ");
    scanf("%f %f", p1,p2);
    if(*p1+*p2 >= 0)
    printf("%f\n", *p1+*p2);
    else
    printf("%f\n", -(*p1+*p2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%lf",p1)` and use `fabs`

Comment: What does "gets wrong" mean? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

if you have to scan doubles you use "lf" and to print them as well. It was your only mistake. "f" it is just for floats.

```
int main(void)
{
    double *p1,*p2, val1,val2;
    p1 = &val1;
    p2 = &val2,
    printf("Enter  two number: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf", p1,p2);
    if(*p1+*p2 >= 0)
        printf("%lf\n", *p1+*p2);
    else
        printf("%lf\n", -(*p1+*p2));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Please consult this website or a similar one for errors or warnings.

%f is used for float values, and c compilers often issue warnings or stop compilation when type conversions occur without specifying them.

%lf is used for doubles.